# How to change general date format in excel?

Tags: excel

Quick but not a simple question for me: How to change the date format in excel so it not only affects how I see the date but also how Excel understands this format?

I mean, I want to have date like 04/13/2018 in cells and I changed to this format (it works fine) but excel still converts it to "13.04.2018" in the text field above the sheet. And It cannot be like that because I have macros built in those cells that keeps throwing errors that date format is still wrong and it needs "MM/DD/YYYY"...

Maybe I can somewhat change my region/locale formats in excel?

Alex

Comment: Have you looked though the right click format as date options which include locale? Otherwise the custom formats.

Comment: Perhaps Excel uses your Windows Regional settings?

Comment: As I said, Its not about How I see the date in my sheet. Macro requires me to enter date format "MM/DD/YYYY" and it ignores how the date is shown to me, for this it is important to actually have those as "MM/DD/YYYY"

Comment: If you are doing this with VBA, you can just use the `Format` function in VBA (i.e. **`Format(Range("A2"), "MM/DD/YYYY"`**)

Answer (score 0):

The result that came out shows that Excel understands that format. If you want to make sure that Excel understands your style of format, then you probably would want to change the DATE and DATE_TEXT function.